How do you turn off an iPhone so it consumes no battery?
I'm not an iPhone user.  I have an iPhone 8 that I need for very rare uses, once every few months.  I fully charge it, turn it off, and put it away.
The battery is always dead when I go to use it. That's not how any other phone or device works, only the iPhone.  I have old Samsung phones that will power up after a year still at 100%.
I press and hold the power button then I "Slide to power off". I'm guessing the phone isn't actually off. (Also guessing it's not possible to but ....) How do you actually turn it off?

You might want to get a small, inexpensive USB power pack, connect it to the iPhone, then power down the iPhone. Whatever power may be used during the time it is shut down should be refreshed by the power pack. Note: powering down the iPhone, then plugging in the power pack will make the iPhone restart, and you will just have to power it down again.

You’re doing everything correctly. The device isn’t working well and a repair will be needed to diagnose it most likely.

@IconDaemon great idea.  I store the old phone in a drawer with some old power packs and spare USB cables.  Geez. It's all right there!  I think bmike is right, the battery is degraded, perhaps not holding charge at all  because it's so old, and if this were my actual phone I'd sense that and replace it. But for what I want, your suggestion is perfect.

And one of those external battery packs will cost a LOT less than an actual iPhone battery replacement.

The iPhone is not completely off. You could try disabling things which may be consuming battery. For example: Do you have "Find My" enabled? If so, the iPhone (when shutdown) will be reporting location to Apple at frequent intervals and this will be consuming the battery. This is a security feature in case of theft.

Note: old power packs suffer from age-related degradation in capacity and duration of service.  If you go this route, try using the newest power pack with the largest capacity. While testing, check the indicator LEDs on the power pack to see the available  power reserve.

@Gilby I'm stupidly receptive to Big-Fruit conspiracy theories but you are saying iphones communicate with airtags and with the FindMy network, using bluetooth and the carrier network respectively, while they are powered off.  Respectully, that is ridiculous.  I guess that's not so respectful.  If that's not "powered on" what is?  I'm looking for some trickle of internal self-maintenance, or something like that, and I think even that is too imaginitive.   The leading theory is the very degraded battery.

From https://screenrant.com/find-lost-iphone-power-off-offline-how/: "Apple's Find My network can be used to track a lost or stolen iPhone, even if it's been turned off or offline. For this to work, Find My Network will need to be enabled on the iPhone before it's lost. The feature is only available on the iPhone 11 and later models." The OP's iPhone is a much early generation, but Apple has this feature enabled, so battery use is a certainty.

@IconDaemon My phone is too old for that, but that is fascinating.  I need to read more about it.  Thank you.

Edit: "... so battery use is a certainty on later models of iPhone."

@IconDaemon see my edit below on how minimal Find My energy usage is for new phones - it’s a rounding error for people worrying about a device keeping charge for a week or a month.

Your Android phones are lying to you. All Lithium-Ion batteries self-discharge, even if not connected to anything. Estimates vary between 0.5% and 5% per month (depends on a number of parameters, such as current charge, temperature, battery health...), so after a year it should be anywhere between 50% and 95%, not 100%. But of course an older battery is more likely to completely run out.

An iPhone with a healthy battery and working circuitry will sit for a year if you charge it fully. For optimal longevity, you want to only charge it to 50% and repeat that half-top-off every 6 months. The battery should retain enough charge to self start in both cases.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/101575

Yours isn’t doing that (or at least that’s my reading of your post), so seek repair for that to determine if it’s the battery that isn’t normal or the device needs a repair. If your battery is degraded and you decide not to repair, try to adapt the above process for your particular needs until it’s time to recycle.
Apple documents the Find My features for people worried about the ultra wide band hardware drawing power when the phone is off. That is a very low power chip and runs for up to 24 hours (up to 5 if the  battery is on reserve). Those chips exist in iPhone 11 and newer, only.
There is no other “off” than the normal shut down procedure. Apple has remote diagnostics, so you can start a repair and get their advice before you have to send the device in or agree to pay if this isn’t covered.

Your diagnosis is probably correct.  It's a very old phone and if I were using it as my phone I would sense the degraded battery performance and replace it.   But as I only take it out for 5 minutes once in a while, and every time the battery is dead, I didn't think "old battery" I just thought "Oh Apple stop doing stuff for me when the phone is off" which I guess is a little cynical. :)    I won't be replacing the battery, I have a better suggestion in the comments.

Yes, external pack and wall power will work until the battery totally failed and drags things down. Glad if I could confirm your suspicions and maybe help others, too.

I am not convinced that a supposedly shutdown iPhone will last for a year.  See my comment to question re Find My.  I too would like to know how to fully shutdown an iPhone so that it is not doing any background tasks.

@Gilby Find My when off relies on ultra wide band hardware which debuted with iPhone 11 and only lasts 5 hours on reserve or 24 hours when you shut the device off. It’s not  relevant for older hardware and even on current devices, not a significant drain when you are talking about weeks or months.

it's not clear from the text if it only runs for up to 24 hours (or 5 if the battery is on reserve) by design to save the battery, or because that's how long the battery lasts when using the feature.  i'm guessing it's the former.

You are doing everything right. Your battery is old and can't hold a charge that long. Your options are

Replacing the battery. Given that you need the  phone only once every few month and Apple will charge you  ca. $70 this may not be a great option.
Periodically recharge to keep it between 15% and 60%. This will maximize the remaining lifetime of the battery (if you care). You would have to figure out experimentally how often and for how long you need to charge. Once a month should be plenty, even for an old clunker
Charge it a few hours before you need it.
Do nothing.  When using it you will have to wait a little longer after you plugged it in and turned it on, but so what? This only happens once every few month.

All in all, option 4 seems like a reasonable thing to do. The deep discharge will further reduce battery life, but as long as it still powers up you are probably fine.

I had an ancient iPod that stopped even powering up, after accidentally leaving it plugged in to the charger for several days.  (I think when it was new, it predated the first iPhones, so hopefully technology has advanced since then in terms of battery management and failsafes.)  But the possibility exists that further harm to the battery could lead to the OP's phone becoming unusable in the long run, perhaps preventable by topping it up or by leaving it plugged into a power bank.  (Although overcharging was correlated with my old iPod refusing to boot even when connected to power.)

Yes @PeterCordes both paths cause eventual failure - charging to any extent will eventually cause it to fail. Deep discharge will eventually become unrecoverable.

I have an iPhone 4 and iPad Gen1 that are both 12+ years old and power up just fine.
